How do I find funded humanities PhDs in the US or Europe?
I am a final-year Master's student with professional experience of 7 years working in gender and development field. I am liking the subject of study and want to pursue a PhD in gender and development studies in any good US or EU universities.
I can't afford to pursue this without financial assistance/aid so how do I get information about funded PhD programmes?

The question here is perfectly legitimate (how does one find information about funded PhD programmes), but the title might evoke down/close votes for being too specific or shooping like.

I agree with Ian - I tweaked the title as well. khkarthik, this site is very biased toward STEM, especially CS/math and will often reflexively close questions about things that aren't that. However, I would suggest that "finding funded PhDs" in the US or Europe are two different tasks (the systems are very different), and you should ask about only one at once. Although there may be questions about this already.

I could be wrong but my impression is that a large fraction of humanities PhD candidates get their funding through individual fellowships that they apply for with documents typically prepared in collaboration with some academic. The notion of organized departmental or institutional PhD programmes is, in general, not as common in the EU as it is in the US.

(Well, as you can guess I come from a STEM background, but have interacted with humanities PhD students.)
I imagine for humanities sometimes it is also field-dependent, but my impression (I am from the US) is that

Good programs have funding. My alma mater's many PhD programs in humanities primarily offer students TAship (or just offer them to teach classes) to allow them to support themselves. See also these programs that I did not cherry pick that explicitly say that the students are funded.
Funding is more scarce than STEM fields, and teaching load is heavier than STEM fields. The stipend might also be lower.

Or you can just send emails and ask some programs that you are interested in. In general, my impression is that the common saying of "if a PhD program needs you to pay instead of paying you, then don't go" equally goes to the humanities.

There are good number of humanities and social sciences doctorate programs at good schools that aren't funded or are only half funded or something. Several of my friends had to at least partly pay their own way.

As a research administrator in the US, I am biased towards the idea that you can find your own funding.  There aren't a lot of opportunities in the humanities for sure, but also you never know what comes up.  One option is to find NSF funding that is targeted for graduate students, typically in the SBE directorate.  Link
You can also search for "graduate student fellowships" across all federal sponsors on grants.gov Link
The NSF GRFP program is meant to be an example where you "bring your own funding" and you should be able to find resources available on that program if your area of focus qualifies.
Otherwise, you just have to accept that you may have to pay tuition, not have a job, and go out of pocket.  Strictly in terms of finance, I would personally advise against this method.  The cost of the program aside, you have to calculate the opportunity cost of not being able to have a job (money and work experience).
Another thing to consider is that if you get a job at a university in the US, many (most?) have education as one of their benefits.  I got my teaching degree part-time at an R2 institution this way.  The cost to me was in taxes, and I didn't pay out of pocket for any class.  I am currently working on two other Masters this way at an R1.  That university's education program will charge me $480 per degree (12 courses) plus any taxes if I can't prove it's job-related.  I also have a full-time salary and 15 years of work-experience.  However, there are restrictions on which programs I can enroll in.  I can't get an MD this way, e.g. But for humanities courses, this tends not to be an issue.  I have taken classes with very prestigious academics this way (those classes cost more, about $400).  You would want to identify an institution to work at, comply with their policies for hiring and find a staff position.  It doesn't have to be related to the field of study.  You just need to be staff and qualify for a tuition remission program according to their HR documentation to get this benefit.  You also generally don't need to apply to the degree program to take classes; you can apply later if it works out.  That's how I got my teaching degree over 5 years instead of the expected 2 years.

There is not going to be any "list".
The steps to take would be to go to the website of institutions you may be interested in, find the department/program you are interested in at that institution, and read the information there that describes the application and funding process. Here's one example, where a "frequently asked questions" page has information about funding, because this is likely to be a frequently asked question:
https://gws.wisc.edu/graduate/phd-program-prospective-students/#frequently-asked-questions
For this particular example, the program says it guarantees 5 years of funding for people who are admitted. Other programs may have similar guarantees, others may not. They will not guarantee you can graduate before funding runs out, that'll be up to you. To find out if you specifically will be funded, you would need to apply. I would expect a lot of competition in applications.
Like this particular example, it's likely your funding will come from a variety of sources. When a program says they guarantee funding for some amount of time, they will still likely encourage you heavily to get your "own" money in various ways, and in the end if you're stuck they are promising to find some work for you, likely as a TA.

As an addendum, it may be possible to be funded after 5 years (in your example), but that depends on the context of that year.
